# Function declared as prototype comes up as undefined

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I have this code, in which there is a particle object and an array to hold all of it's instances. Then, I am trying to make a function that will call each of the instances' draw() and update() functions.:

```
var particles;
function setup() {
    createCanvas(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    particles = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        particles.push(1);
    }
};
function particle() {
    this.x = random(0, width);
    this.y = random(0, height);
};
particle.prototype.draw = function() {
    noStroke();
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    rect(this.x, this.y, 20, 20);
};
particle.prototype.update = function() {
    this.x+=random(-0.1, 0.1);
    this.y+=random(-0.1, 0.1);
};
Array.prototype.run = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        this[i].update();
        this[i].draw();
    }
};

function draw() {
    background(255);
    particles.run();
};
```

Here's my error message: `this[i].update is not a function`. If I log the function, it's "undefined". Does this have something to do with the fact that I declared it as a prototype? I also know it's generally bad practice to modify the Array object, but as of now I know no other way of creating a function that can be used directly on arrays. I am using no libraries or content other than the p5 library. What would be the most efficient/clean solution to this?

Comment: particles is an array, of numbers - you haven't instantiated particle anywhere in that code. And why would `particle.prototype.update` be added to the number prototype?

Comment: I agree with Jaromanda, and also where does setup get called?

Comment: to clarify ... `this[i]` would always be `1` because you `particles.push(1);` - so particles is `[1,1,1,1,1]` - the `update`/`draw` functions are methods of `particle`, not `Number`

Comment: You probably should be doing `this.particles.push(new particle)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you actually want particles to be an array of Particle's

Note 1: the code to add `run` to `particles` array **only**

Note 2: changed `particle` to `Particle` - for "convention" reasons only

```
var particles;
function setup() {
    createCanvas(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    particles = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        particles.push(new Particle);
    }
};
function Particle() {
    this.x = random(0, width);
    this.y = random(0, height);
};
Particle.prototype.draw = function() {
    noStroke();
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    rect(this.x, this.y, 20, 20);
};
Particle.prototype.update = function() {
    this.x+=random(-0.1, 0.1);
    this.y+=random(-0.1, 0.1);
};
// add run to particles, not to Array.prototype
Object.defineProperty(particles, 'run', {
    value: function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
            this[i].update();
            this[i].draw();
        }
    }
});

function draw() {
    background(255);
    particles.run();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `setup()` function is creating an array of numbers, not an array of `particle`. It should be:

```
function setup() {
    createCanvas(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    particles = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        particles.push(new particle);
    }
};
```